# Find The Moving Average for Amount of Last 30 Days for each user Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, apply, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to calculate the average amount for each user's transaction. What I mean is for each transaction, find the last 30 days transaction of that specific user and get the average amount of those transactions.

Data: https://data.world/oklahoma/purchase-card-fiscal-year

As a solution, which I don't find fancy, I try to use `apply` method such as

```
...
import swifter

transcations['Transaction_date_before_30day'] = pd.to_datetime(transcations['Transaction Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p') - timedelta(days=30)   
transcations['Transaction_date_before_90day'] = pd.to_datetime(transcations['Transaction Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p') - timedelta(days=90)

#transcations is the Pandas DataFrame for the csv

def txn_amount_over_month(double_col):
      temp_df = transcations[(transcations.userId == double_col[1] ) & (transcations['Transaction Date'] >= double_col[0]) ]
      if len(temp_df) == 0:
        return 0
      return (temp_df.Amount.sum()) / len(temp_df)

transcations['txn_amount_over_month'] = transcations[['Transaction_date_before_30day','userId']].swifter.apply(txn_amount_over_month, axis=1)
```

But it takes too long as expected, about 3-4 hours.

I tried to use `rolling` method for pandas but I couldn't make it.

Thanks in advance,